# Getting the size right for the malloc function

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I often find myself spending a lot of time figuring out how I should properly size a `malloc` when I have a non-obvious type. Here is an example:

```
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    char* value;
} hash_item;

typedef struct {
    int size;          // max size of the table
    int count;         // how many items are currently in the table
    hash_item** items; // will have size * hash_items in the array
} hash_table;
```

Now, when I create a new hashtable, I'll do something like this:

```
hash_table *table = malloc(sizeof(hash_table));
table->items      = malloc(sizeof(*hash_item) * size); // this is tricky for me
```

Is that 'sizing' correct? And how do I know that `sizeof(*hash_item)` is the correct unit-size, and not for example:

- `sizeof(hash_item)`
- `sizeof(table->items[0])`
- `sizeof(*(table->items))`

Is there a good rule of tumb for how to size a `malloc` when it's referring to a non-primitive data-type?

Comment: This is wrong. `sizeof(*hash_item)` is wrong syntax.

Comment: The rult of thumb is: one extra `*` or `[]` :: `hash_table *table = malloc(sizeof *table);`

Comment: @wildplasser what about the second malloc?

Comment: Also `sizeof(table->items[0])` and `sizeof(*(table->items))` are correct, so you shouldn't know that they are not correct unit-size.

Comment: `table->items  = malloc(sizeof table->items[0] * count);`

Comment: One thumb rule could be `SomeType* ptr = malloc(sizeof (*ptr) * count)` with the default `count = 1`.

Comment: @zoso would `ptr` be `table->items` in the above example ?

Comment: @carl.hiass That's right.  Basically one thing, `malloc` is always going to return a pointer. So now one just need to sort of _unify_  `SomeType* ptr` with `table->items`and hence one gets `malloc(sizeof (*table->items) * countOfItems)`. I hope that makes sense. Take the `ptr` on LHS, de-reference it inside `malloc()` and if required, multiply the count. Also, one thing, no need to bother about `NULL` dereference since well...`sizeof` is a compile-time operator.

Comment: A tip to ensure consistency: Set your `size` and `count` members *first* and then use `size` in your `malloc` computation.

Comment: @ZanLynx could you please clarify? What would the malloc look like in that case?

Comment: @carl.hiass: `table->size = 233;` then `table->items = malloc(sizeof *table->items * table->size);` and that way you have always allocated the number of items that your struct has recorded and a careless code edit later does not break it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally do not need to use types in the `malloc` size, and you should avoid it. You can use a “sample object” instead:

```
PointerToThing = malloc(NumberOfThings * sizeof *PointerToThing);
```

So that is very simple: `*PointerToThing` is the type of thing being pointed to, so its size is what you want.

Further, it reduces the chances of certain errors:

- If you try typing a type description for what `PointerToThing` points to, you can make a mistake. `*PointerToThing` is simple, so people are less likely to make a mistake with it, especially once it becomes habit.
- If you are modifying the program in the future and change the type of `PointerToThing`, you have to remember to also search for everywhere that type is used and change it there too. With the method above, the type does not appear, so it cannot be overlooked—there is no change to make when the type changes; the `sizeof` adapts automatically to whatever type `*PointerToThing` is.

And `PointerToThing` does not have to be a simple variable. It can be an expression, such as `table->items`, for which you could use `malloc(NumberOfItems * sizeof *table->items)`.